# navbar-right not working in form_tag using bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having problems getting `navbar-right` to work correctly when using `form_tag`. When I use `form_tag` I seem to lose all of the `navbar-right` styling and everything floats to the left.  If I just use a pure HTML `<form>` tag then everything floats to the right as expected.

Here are my gem versions:

```
rails (4.1.1)
bootstrap-sass (3.1.1.1)
```

Here is the code I'm using that isn't working:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
              data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <%= link_to "Football Pool Mania", root_path, 
                  class:'navbar-brand' %>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<!-- This is the line with an issue -->

      <%= form_tag(sessions_path, class: 'navbar-form nabvar-right', 
                   role: 'form') do %>
<!-- -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email],
              class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Email"%>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= password_field_tag :password, nil,
              class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Password"%>
        </div>
        <%= submit_tag "Sign in", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</header>
```

Here is what it looks like when using form_tag:

[image]

Here is the raw HTML when it doesn't work:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
              data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Football Pool Mania</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/sessions" class="navbar-form nabvar-right" method="post" role="form"><div style="display:none"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="mhM8pSrINO2rfH9JbRm7I4J+iSCAsrEnoYVBPDcIYu0=" /></div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" />
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign in" />
      </form>
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</header>
```

If I replace the form_tag line with a straight `<form>` HTML line as follows, then it works.

```
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right"action="/sessions" method="post" role="form" >
```

This is how it looks (and what I'm wanting) when using straight HTML:

```
![enter image description here][2]
```

Here is the raw HTML when it works:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
              data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Football Pool Mania</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" >
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" />
        </div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign in" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

The only thing I can notice is form_tag adds the input for the authenticity token for my session management but I'm not sure why that would break the styling for the form itself.  I've been looking at this for too long to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form is not aligned to the right, because you have a typo in your code.

You mistiped the class navbar-right (in your example it is nabvar-right).

```
<!-- <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/sessions" class="navbar-form nabvar-right" method="post" role="form"> -->
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/sessions" class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="post" role="form">
```

Here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SJu82/

I used a diff tool to spot the difference.

Comment: Wow! Since I'm new to using Bootstrap I was convinced I had just done something wrong in the coding and I completely overlooked the typo. I can't believe I looked at that so many times and didn't notice the darn typo.  Thanks for the help!